# java 8 nested null check list of objects

Tags: java-8, option-type

I am trying to do a nested null check and then clear the values in map in the nested object if the map is not null.

The following is my hypothetical code. I am wondering if this is the right way to do it or is there a more elegant solution to this.

```
package exp.myJavaLab.Experiments;

    import java.util.*;

    public class OptionalTest {

        public Inner inner;

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            OptionalTest testObj = new OptionalTest();
            Pojo pojo1 = new Pojo();
            pojo1.id = 1;
            Map<String, String> dataMap = new HashMap<>();
            dataMap.put("a","b");
            pojo1.dataMap = dataMap;
            Pojo pojo2 = new Pojo();
            pojo2.id = 2;

            Inner inner = new Inner();
            inner.pojoList = Arrays.asList(pojo1, pojo2);

            testObj.inner = inner;

            System.out.println(testObj);

            Optional.ofNullable(testObj.inner)
            .map(Inner::getPojoList)
            .ifPresent(pojos -> pojos.forEach(pojo -> {
                    if (pojo.getDataMap() != null) {
                        pojo.getDataMap().clear();
                    }
                }));

            System.out.println(testObj);

        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("OptionalTest{");
            sb.append("inner=").append(inner);
            sb.append('}');
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }

    class Inner {
        public List<Pojo> pojoList;

        public List<Pojo> getPojoList() {
            return pojoList;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Inner{");
            sb.append("pojoList=").append(pojoList);
            sb.append('}');
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }

    class Pojo {

        public Map<String, String> dataMap;
        public int id;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Pojo{");
            sb.append("dataMap=").append(dataMap);
            sb.append(", id=").append(id);
            sb.append('}');
            return sb.toString();
        }

        public Map<String, String> getDataMap() {
            return dataMap;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `pojos.stream().map(Pojo::getDataMap).filter(Objects::nonNull).forEach(Map::clear)`

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion Collections should never be null.

You could declare your `pojoList` and `dataMap` as `private` and instantiate them.
Your class then needs some `add`-methods. So you are sure `getDataMap()` never returns `null`:

```
class Pojo {
    private Map<String, String> dataMap = new HashMap<>();

    public Map<String, String> getDataMap() {
        return dataMap;
    }

    public void add(String key, String value) {
        dataMap.put(key, value);
    }
}
```

Then you don't need to check for `null`:

```
Optional.ofNullable(testObj.inner)
.map(Inner::getPojoList)
.ifPresent(pojos -> pojos.forEach(pojo -> { pojo.getDataMap().clear(); }));
```

Comment: If you straight-forwardly apply the “Collections should never be null” rule to `getPojoList()` as well, you can simplify the code even further: `Optional.ofNullable(testObj.inner).ifPresent(inner -> inner.getPojoList().forEach(pojo -> pojo.getDataMap().clear()));`

Comment: @Obeland thanks for your answer, but the above code is a hypothetical. So my actual code does have getter and setters. My code gets generated and hence have no control over the getters and setters